# Implementing Android (no 3rd party) Listview Subheaders

Tags: android, listview, sectionheader

is there any possibility to implement the subheader behaviour as suggested by the google guidelines (see: https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/subheaders.html)?
Especially the sticky functionality of the headers is important for me.

I found different libraries on github (e.g. https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders), but i wonder if there is a direct support in the android sdk.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want them sticky, 
and exactly know what positions the headers are going to be( in your data array),
then you could simply use following trick :

header is just another list item type,

so extend BaseAdapter and override following methods :

```
@Override
getViewTypeCount(){
    return 2;// 1(list items) + 1(for header)
}

@Override
getItemViewType(int position){
if(want to show header at position)
    return 1; // header item
else
    return 0;// regular items
}

@Override
getView(int pos,....)
{
    if(getItemViewType(pos)==0){// regular item
        inflate/reuse convertView; // cast to regular item & bind data
    } else {
        inflate/reuse convertView; // cast to hdr view and bind data 
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

for detailed analysis you could follow this link :
http://cyrilmottier.com/2011/07/05/listview-tips-tricks-2-section-your-listview/

Comment: thanks, but i want them sticky :) - i will update the question